# Push notification - can I use any mobile auth application?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

When generating a OTP, I know I can use either Authy or Google Auth, either can scan the code & generate the same OTP.

What about push notification? Are Duo/Okta verify and other apps interchangeable? I am trying to limit the number of apps on my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the respective websites those apps are specific to one service.

I am not aware of a generic "push" protocol. So if you want to get that form of push notification from a service you will have to install the matching app.